# Rails not recognizing a route in production but doing fine with recognize_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a quite complex routing scheme, everything is fine when I test it using the console, but explodes in production with a Routing Error: No route matches.

routes

```
resources :sports, :only => [ :show ] do
  member do
    get ':page', :to => 'sports#facilities'
  end
end

resources :provinces, :path => '', :only => [ :show ] do
  resources :municipalities, :path => '', :only => [ :show ] do
    resources :neighbourhoods, :path => '', :only => [ :show ] do
      resources :sports, :only => [ :show ] do
        member do
          get ':page', :to => 'sports#facilities'
        end
      end
    end
    resources :sports, :only => [ :show ] do
      member do
        get ':page', :to => 'sports#facilities'
      end
    end
  end

  resources :sports, :only => [ :show ] do
    member do
      get ':page', :to => 'sports#facilities'
      get 'deals'
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I do to see if the route is correctly recognized:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > r = Rails.application.routes
 => #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fa7f3a0edb0> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > r.recognize_path( '/milano/milano/sports/tennis' )
 => {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sports", :province_id=>"milano", :municipality_id=>"milano", :id=>"tennis"} 
1.9.3p194 :003 > r.recognize_path( '/milano/milano/sports/tennis/1' )
 => {:controller=>"sports", :action=>"facilities", :province_id=>"milano", :municipality_id=>"milano", :id=>"tennis", :page=>"1"} 
1.9.3p194 :004 > r.recognize_path( '/sports/tennis/1' )
 => {:controller=>"sports", :action=>"facilities", :id=>"tennis", :page=>"1"}
```

When I try the same in production, I see that :page is nil, and the path is not recognize. It's exactly the same page. To add to the weirdness, if the page has a syntax error or something, the exception it raises is the one raised inside the page, when I fix it, I have a routing error...

The params passed to the controller are {:controller=>"sports", :action=>"facilities", :id=>"tennis", :page=>nil}, and it's always like that, even when I use /2 /3.

Someone ever experienced anything like that and can help me?

Rails is 3.2.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you by any chance run your rails migration for the production database environment?

Comment: Yes, absolutely yes. To clarify: it doesn't work on the server, even if it's webrick on dev. It works only on the console...

Comment: That is very strange. Does it work on production console remotely? I guess not.. ? Also does it blow up on any method of `recognize_path`?

Comment: Everything works perfectly with recognize_path in console. It only blows when actually running on a server, on every environment, both locally and in production... Maybe this is a rack thing?

Comment: What is the stack error?